# Auto increment primary key in sugar orm

Tags: android, sugarorm

How can define an auto increment primary key in Sugar model?
Do Sugar automatically creates unique ID for each record

```
import com.orm.SugarRecord;

public class Customers extends SugarRecord {

    int id; // this field must be auto increment primary key
    String name;
    String tel;
    String mobile;
    String address;
    String create_date;

    public Customers(){}

    public Customers(int id, String name, String tel, String mobile, String address, String create_date){
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.tel = tel;
        this.mobile = mobile;
        this.address = address;
        this.create_date = create_date;
    }
}
```

Comment: Answer: https://github.com/satyan/sugar/issues/593

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may create a custom table my annotating your class with "@Table", but you should create a long type of "id" for the ORM to work with. The best way would be to let sugar do all the work.

Sugar *will* create an id field (you do not need to include in your class) and you may access it using "getId()" something like:

```
Customers customer = Customers.findById(Customers.class, 1)
long customer_id = customer.getId();
```